# Autosaving a Knockout viewmodel on tab navigation - how to get view model bound to DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to call my save methods on a Knockout viewmodel when a user navigates **away** from a tab (Bootstrap 2)

This works to fire a save when the tab is shown

```
//This section should save when flipped away from
<a href="#cardiovascular" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="event: { shown: cardio.save }">Cardio</a>

//Click handler works here as well, navigating from Cardio to Respiratory should save Cardio
<a href="#respiratory" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: respiratory.save">Respiratory</a>
```

This is given by the documentation of Bootstrap for events that can be bound to on the tabs

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    e.target // activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

Is there any way that I can get the binding context of the previous tab and save it? My only idea was in the main viewmodel writing a function with a switch or if/elseif that would evaluate the tab selected and call that save method but that seems sloppy

In my Knockout viewmodel, I've got nested viewmodels like this

```
var mainViewModel = function() {
    self.cardio = new cardioViewModel();
}

var cardioViewModel = function() {
   self.save = function() {
     //ajax call here
   }
}
```

and each nested viewmodel has a `save` method on it

### EDIT

So per the selected answer below, I've got the following script

```
$('#generalAssessment a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    var boundElement = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href");

    context = ko.contextFor($(boundElement)[0]);
})
```

The idea being that the Bootstrap tab's target is the element that has `data-bind="with: whateverViewModel"` attached to it. Below is the code for the tab pane itself bound to a child viewmodel

```
<div id="cardiovascular" class="active tab-pane" data-bind="with:cardio">
    //All of my viewmodel stuff is bound here
</div>
```

However doing `ko.contextFor` or `ko.dataFor` is giving me the root viewmodel in this case, `mainViewModel` instead of the viewmodel that is bound by the `with` clause, which is `cardioViewModel`. Is there any way to reference **that** context easily?

### EDIT 2

Since the `ko.dataFor` or `ko.contextFor` gets the context of the binding on the selected element, the tab itself is still bound by the `mainViewModel`, so that's working as expected.

I just have to traverse down an extra element that is bound with the child viewmodel and opted to do the following

```
var boundElement = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("href");
var boundWithContext = $(boundElement).children().first();

ko.contextFor($(boundWithContext)[0]);
```

This will get me the selected tab-pane, so in this case

```
<div id="cardiovascular" class="active tab-pane" data-bind="with:cardio">
    //All of my viewmodel stuff is bound here
</div>
```

and then pick out whatever the first child element is underneath that that could be bound in the new context, which in this case is a `<h4>` without any binding context

```
 <h4 class="muted">Cardiovascular</h4>
```

Logging that to the console picks up the appropriate stuff I was looking for

```
{ 
  $data: cardioViewModel,
  $parent: mainVieModel,
  $rawData: cardioViewModel,
  $root: mainViewModel
}
```

so from there I should be able to call `$data.save()` and all will be well! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I didn't understand your question at first, but now I have updated my answer, and I think this time I'm giving what you need, and related docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bootstrap `shown` event, you can use the `ko.dataFor(element)` or `ko.contextFor(element)` to determine the view model bound to the current/previous tab. You have the docs for `ko.dataFor` and `ko.contextFor` here: [Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html). Of course, if you didn't bind directly to the tab element, you can use [jQuery traversing functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to look for the bound element inside the tab.

`dataFor` can return a simple observable, depending on the passed element. `contextFor` will give access to the whole context: the bound observable or view model, the `$parent`, the `$root`, etc.

For example, if you called 'ko.dataFor($('#cardiovascular')[0])' you'd get the `cardioViewModel`. Remember that you must pass a DOM element, not a jQuery collections, that's way you need to appedn the [0] after the selector.

Comment: I think I can make that work! Thanks! I knew that Knockout had something to get this done but couldn't figure out what for the life of me.

Comment: This is 99% there, but I'm going to update my question with more information to solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I think I got it! Updating the question with a second edit. If you have a better idea than what I came up with though, it's much appreciated!

Comment: No, no better option than this. Note the "you can use jQuery traversing functions to look for the bound element inside the tab" in my answer. It was totally intentional. However according to bootstrap tabs plugin docs, this should suffice: `var boundElement = $(e.relatedTarget).children()[0];` And then `ko.contextFor(boundElement)` should give you the same result. I can't understand why you extract the `href` attribute, and then use it to get the tab element, but I don't have experience with bootstrap tabs, so I can be wrong. However you can omit the `first()` in `children().first()[0]`).

Comment: The `href` holds the ID of the tab panel it needs to show. I use that ID to find the tab panel which has my child viewmodel bound to it. The `e.relatedTarget` just gives me the previous tab's element, and I don't need that.

Comment: ;) Didn't I tell you I had no experience with bootstrap tabs? ;) So you can only make the simplification of removing the `first()`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `relatedTarget` within your current method to get the previous tab

```
e.relatedTarget // previous tab
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

Comment: You're missing the point of what I'm trying to do though. I'm trying to use that previous tab `e.relatedTarget` and get the data context it's bound to with Knockout, or implement a function that could call the ajax save on my Knockout viewmodel

Comment: are you binding a different context to each tab or are they all contained in one ko model?

Comment: As noted above, I've got my `mainViewModel` that has nested child viewModels. My page is bound with those child view models using a `with` Knockout binding